# Mapping java generics to json using JsonParser and ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, generics, casting, mapper

So i have a service which make calls to an API and it returns a JsonParser object that will be mapped to a class. It works perfect repeating the same code multiple times just changing:

```
new TypeReference<ActualClass>() {}
```

For example:

```
new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Model>>>() {}
```

I am trying to make a cleaner and better code by creating a generic way to do this. I tried using a generic method, but it is not possible or I could not do it.

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, Connection connection, ObjectMapper mapper, String errorMessage) { ... }
```

I can't pass some classes like:

```
get(List<Map<String, Model>>.class <- this will fail.
```

So I tried to use a generic class:

```
private static class Executor<T> {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private Connection connection;
    private String errorMessage;

    public Executor(Connection connection, ObjectMapper mapper, String errorMeesage) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.connection = connection;
        this.errorMessage = errorMeesage;
    }

    public T get(final String url) {
        T result = null;
        JsonParser dataReceived = null;

        try {
            dataReceived = connection.getData(url);

            if (dataReceived != null) {
                result = mapper.readValue(dataReceived, new TypeReference<T>() {});
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(errorMessage, e);
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

It compiles, but I am getting this error: .lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ...

I read a little and I think this has to be some kind of limitation of Java. Help will be appreciated :), thanks.

Comment: `new TypeReference<T>() {}` will not work - read up on "type erasure" and "super type tokens".

Comment: i will read about that, thx!